# Merge Mysql Column output as comma seperated in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a simple query with outputs only one column (rows number may change)

```
SELECT column1 as NUMBER WHERE column1 ...
```

Output,

```
NUMBER
  1
  2
```

I just want it as an array in PHP with them as comma seperated.

So I did,

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
```

and its working if I echo it with print_r

However because of some reason I cant get the plain values out of this array.

echo $rows[0] gives me the word 'Array'

echo implode(",", $rows); gives me 1Array',Array1

I tried

```
echo json_encode($rows[0]);
```

gives me

```
["1"]
```

I simply want 1,2

After a lot of different tries I gave up and added group_concat in the sql query. I just want to know what I did wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: instead of `$rows[] = $row;` why not `$rows[] = $row['column1'];`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`column1` SEPARATOR ',') AS number FROM table where....
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_row i returning a single element array. To have your desired output, only select the 1st element:

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

foreach($rows as $key => $value){

}

should do the trick, with an echo it will output the results as an associative array

Answer (score 0):

just make a simple amendment to your code:

```
$rows[] = $row;
```

into:

```
$rows[] = $row[0];
```

and use:

```
implode(", ", $rows[]);
```